# Can't seem to get the exclude in the convert extension working using a filemap with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, filemap

I am trying to use the convert extension in Mercurial to create a repository from a folder currently in our "Main" repository. I am using the filemap to move (rename) this new repository to a new location however it keeps copying over all files. I know in the filemap we can have an exclude but it does not seem to work.

Sample of what I am doing:

```
    #Exclude everything but sa-inetpub website and the sa-inetpub.Tests
    exclude .

    #Include folder Source/Code/Websites/sa-inetpub and the Source/UnitTests/sa-inetpub.Tests
    include "Source/Code/Websites/sa-inetpub"
    include "Source/UnitTests/sa-inetpub.Tests"
    include "Source/Code/MVC"
    include "Source/Code/MVCUnitTests"
    include "Source/Code/Websites/Includes/HierarchyParser"   

    #Rename the old sa-inetpub in the old directory to the new sa-inetpub directory. This is essentially a move. 
    rename Source/Code/Websites/sa-inetpub src/app/sa-inetpub
    rename Source/UnitTests/sa-inetpub.Tests src/test/sa-inetpub.Tests

    rename Source/Code/MVC src/app/MVC
    rename Source/Code/MVCUnitTests src/test/MVCUnitTests

    rename Source/Code/Websites/Includes/HierarchyParser src/app/hierarchyparser
```

According to the documentation on the ConvertExtension this should work:

```
exclude "doc"
include "doc/foo bar.txt"
rename "doc/FAQ" "faq"
```

Can someone please provide some insight on this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but I got it. 
You do not need the exclude. The include will only brings files/folders mentioned.